# Break PowerShell Script when dotnet test fails

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, dotnet-test

In a small PowerShell build script I build and test a .NET application.

I now want to prevent further steps in the script if the tests result in one or more failures.

I tried to get the result of the test like this:

```
$exitcode = dotnet test  .\Domain.Tests
Write-Host "result $exitcode"
```

but unfortunately it doesn't return an exit code indicating success I just get the test testing description.

Is there a better way then parsing the string output for the failed tests count?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `$lastexitcode` automatic variable, you can check that for the exit code.

Comment: `$?` - use this. easily searchable on the web

Comment: I meant in `cmd`, I found it actually after posting comment here, but forgot to remove the comment.

Comment: It is `%ERRORLEVEL%` btw, e.g: `IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO Failure`